# integration of Feature Selection in Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I have noticed integrating feature selection in a pipeline alters results.

Pipeline 1 gives slightly different results with pipeline 2. Why should this be so?

**Pipeline 2**

```
 # Integrate selection in pipeline
    select = SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2, percentile=50)
    pipeline_selection = make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(preprocess_data),
        encode_transformer,
        
        poly_transformer,
        
        select,
        LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000)
        
        
       
    
    )
    # Define the parameter grid for grid search
    param_grid = {
        'logisticregression__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100],
        'logisticregression__penalty': ['l1','l2'],
        'logisticregression__solver': ['liblinear', 'saga','newton-cg']
    }
    
    # Create the logistic regression grid search object with cross-validation
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline_selection, param_grid, cv=5,return_train_score=True)
    
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Get the best parameters and best score
    best_params = grid_search.best_params_
    best_score = grid_search.best_score_
    
    print("Best Parameters:", best_params)
    print("Best Score:", best_score)
```

**Pipeline 1**

```
encode_transformer = make_column_transformer(
     
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['Sex','Pclass','Title']),
    
     (MinMaxScaler(), ['Age']),
    
    (FunctionTransformer(boxcox_transform), ['Fare']), 
)


# Create the polynomial transformer
poly_transformer = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)


# Create the pipeline by chaining the column transformers
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(preprocess_data),
    encode_transformer,
    
    poly_transformer
    
    
)
poly_transformed_df = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)


select = SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2, percentile=50)
best = select.fit(poly_transformed_df, y_train)
X_train_poly_selected = select.transform(poly_transformed_df)

parameters = {
    'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100],
    'penalty': ['l2'],
    'solver': ['liblinear', 'saga','newton-cg']
}

clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000), parameters, cv=5, return_train_score=False)
clf.fit(X_train_poly_selected, y_train)

print(clf.best_params_)

print(clf.best_score_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Pipeline 2

If you do preprocessing (selction, transformation, ...) inside the Pipeline, it will be part of the cross-validation and only trained on the training dataset. Doing so will prevent some information leakage from the validation sets into the cross-validation models.

###### Schema

[image]
This schema shows how for each model inside the cross-validation (gray box) a different feature selection is performed. In this schema, I assumed that the number of features is not fixed and, hence, one model gets 5 features.

##### Pipeline 1

If you do the preprocessing outside of the Pipeline, it is just performed once. This might result in different selected features as in Pipeline 2.

###### Schema

[image]

**Note**: What you call `X_train` and `y_train` (Schema: white table outside the gray cross-validation box) will be further split by `GridSearchCV` into folds and from these folds train (Schema:
white) and validation (Schema: orange) sets will be build. So your `y_train` is not the training set that the pipeline sees in it's `fit`-methods

Comment: I think, I will add an image to visualize what I mean. It might take a while until I find time for it

Comment: Hope this makes it clearer